Affection, thing in themselves and sensations
I have a question about Kant, specifically regarding Wayne Waxman's psychological interpretation (other interpretations are also welcome).
According to this psychological interpretation, the matter of appearances is something that corresponds to sensation, although they are not identical. Sensations are not ordered, but rather the matter of appearances, or more specifically the reality indicated by them. Sensations are nothing more than modifications of the subject's state, they do not have any order or form, nor do they require consciousness. They correspond to but are not identified with the matter of an object. To be more explicit, sensations are displayed in space and time, but they do not have a space-time form (the smell of something is not triangular, someone's envy does not take up more space than my thirst, etc.). So, for example, a car. Light, smell, color, etc., are all sensations. This sensation corresponds to what, in the object, are its physical qualities that "cause" these subjective effects (in scientific terms: its gases, bodily matter, electromagnetic waves, etc.). These physical qualities are determined in accordance with a space-time form, which only exists in the mind, and is what allows us to identify the matter of the object in order to differentiate it from sensations (which have no space-time form). So, through the idealization of space and time, you can distinguish the two things.
This is a basic and contextual explanation of the psychological interpretation. Now, I can move on to my questions. I would appreciate it if someone who is familiar with this line of interpretation could help me. Thanks!
My doubt fundamentally concerns affection, the thing in itself and the matter of appearances, and how these things relate.

The senses are affected. (But are they affected by what? By the thing in itself? By the matter of appearances? Or by both?)
From these affections, sensations arise.
Sensations make the synopsis of the multiple. (The multiple is the diversity of the real and the synopsis consists of simply carrying the real in sensations. But what is this real? Is it the matter of appearances or the thing in itself?)

To be more specific, if what affects us and causes sensations in us is the thing in itself, then what, after all, is the matter of appearances? Sensations indicate something real, an existing thing that affects us and causes sensations in us. And this something real can be the thing in itself or the matter of appearances. But the matter of appearances, as something belonging to the empirical realm, can be thought in physical terms, for example, the physical qualities of objects such as sound waves that produce sensations in us, or our visual senses that are affected by light in a certain way and this generates sensations in us. So, in the end, what is the relationship between the matter of appearances and the thing in itself? That the thing in itself is related to sensations, that seems clearer, but that the thing in itself is related to the matter of appearances, that I still don't quite understand. What seems to be the case to me is that we are affected by both the thing in itself and the matter of appearances, and both are responsible for sensations in us. But this brings up other questions: Are there two affections occurring? Or are both the thing in itself and the matter of appearances the same thing ontologically, albeit under different aspects, so that only one affection occurs? Can the thing in itself cause something in us, can it affect us? Because, since causality is a category of understanding, we cannot speak of a causal relationship when it comes from the thing in itself. So, if it is not possible to say anything about the thing in itself, if it is nothing for us, how can we affirm that it exists (even if it is unknowable)? So what would be its role, the thing in itself, on the knowing subject?

For Kant the thing in itself cannot affect us directly in the way that phenomena do, as we cannot experience it directly, any causal interaction with it is mediated by the structures of our experience. The matter of appearances is what affects us through our senses. However, the thing in itself is responsible for the grounding of appearances. Indeed sensations aren't ordered or structured by space-time, the ordering happens later as the mind imposes structure onto these sensations. Kant claimed we cannot know the thing in itself, but we can affirm its existence due to its causal grounding.

What's mean this grounding of appearances and the causal grounding? How it works?

If the thing-in-itself has no meaning in the said symbol grounding problem, then it would've been removed by Occam's razor long ago. Phenomenal is always the 'epi' or 'apparent' of the underlying noumenal, so according to the conventional dictum to be is to cause,  only the underlying entity can cause the appearance and epis, thus is real but unaccessible to our knowledge per Kantian constructive epistemology, though he admits or accepts the existence of thing-in-itself in a non-constructive way like the well known case in accepting classic logic's LEM...
